# Intuitive explanation of the term manifold

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, machine-learning

I am reading Christopher Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" and in the first chapter, where he talks about the curse of dimensionality, he gives the following example:

> Consider, for example, an application
>   in manufacturing in which images are captured of identical planar objects on a conveyor
>   belt, in which the goal is to determine their orientation. Each image is a point in a high-dimensional space whose dimensionality is determined by the number of
>   pixels. Because the objects can occur at different positions within the image and
>   in different orientations, there are three degrees of freedom of variability between
>   images, and a set of images will live on a three dimensional manifold embedded
>   within the high-dimensional space. Due to the complex relationships between the
>   object position or orientation and the pixel intensities, this manifold will be highly
>   nonlinear. If the goal is to learn a model that can take an input image and output the
>   orientation of the object irrespective of its position, then there is only one degree of
>   freedom of variability within the manifold that is significant.

I haven't took a course on differential geometry before; but I have some informal ideas on what manifolds are. I thought them as low dimensional continuous (not in a rigorous way) subsets of high dimensional Euclidean Spaces. For example, a curved surface of a blanket can be considered as a manifold in the space of a room.

Well, that explanation does not work when it comes to a more rigorous text like in the above. How should I understand the term "manifold" in the context of the above paragraph? I see that there is a high dimensional space, with the dimension equal to the number of pixels in the given images. But the definition of the three dimensional manifold is not exactly a three dimensional ("three pixel" sized images) subset of the image pixels exactly. It sounds like that a transformation function is applied to each point (image) in this high dimensional space and each high dimensional point is mapped to a three dimensional point in some three dimensional space. (Consisting of x,y coordinates and an orientation angle). But I don't see how this is related with a manifold. So, how should I understand the term "manifold" in such a context, in an informal and intuitive way? Is this something completely different from my sloppy understanding of the term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's true that any manifold can be imbedded in some high dimensional Euclidean space, modern mathematics does not see this as the right way to think about them. A manifold is an object such that if you look at a tiny piece of it, it will behave like a Euclidean space, which you can take to mean that you can parameterize it with coordinates. An example is the surface of a planet. A planet is so large compared to a person that the overall spherical nature is not visible to a person on the surface. Rather, the space around the person seems to be essentially flat (barring terrain irregularities).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So; can I think about the quoted text that it refers to a three dimensional subset of the image space such that we can parametrize it with the 2D location and orientation of the objects. Is that right?

Comment: If the subset is three dimensional, then you will parameterize the local charts with 3 coordinates. The surface of a planet is a two-dimensional manifold.